# Eclipse Plugine Development for Popup menu

Tags: eclipse, plugins

How can i add the my menu item inside the Run as menu item in pop up menu.

Thanks and Regards 
Rahul Nakate

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you have to extend the extension point **org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes** and implement **org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationDelegate**.

How to implement your own run configuration is a big topic. I would suggest to read the following: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html